# Cannot Load clui.dll

Tags: c++, sfml

for some reason when i try to compile and run this program following the Official SFML Website [Tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-vc.php):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error  C1510   Cannot load language resource clui.dll. SFMLPractice1   >c:\Users\NAME\documents\visual studio >2015\Projects\SFMLPractice1\SFMLPractice1\CL    1

I need help on sorting this out.. Please Help!

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory. Your program is looking for a DLL, clui.dll, and can't find it. Try placing that file in the same directory as your program.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider im preety sure the problem was earlier i tried to uninstall visual studio,then stoped in the middle of it.. So now im reparing Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0):

You can move on to Visual Studio 2017 and install "VC++ 2015.3 v14.00 (v140) toolset for desktop". clui.dll seems to be inside this component.

[image: Try this component]